# upload contacts from iphone/mac to django app

Tags: django, contacts

I am trying to understand if there is a way to upload/sync all my contacts on the contacts app of my mac/iphone with my django app. Any help?

Comment: You need your client code to send post requests with the required contact data. If you have got android app, make it read the contact data, and send it via post request to your django app or something.

Comment: wait, so I am trying to bring the contacts into django...that's what you are suggesting as well right?